# Como hacer variables reactivas entre COMPONENTES? Angular 2 / 4

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Buenas Stackeros, Hoy os propongo un duda que no logro encontrar o identificar.

Ultimamente estoy practicando con los **Inputs/Outputs** y esto me ha llevado hacer este ejemplo:

En el componente A, tengo `@Output() outputVariableA = [hola, hola2, hola3]`

En el componente B, tengo `@Input() inputVariableB [];`

En el componente B, defino una **funcion**  que me modifica el **inputVariableB**.

¿Como hago para que sea REACTIVO, entre las dos VARIABLES la modificacion.

> Si no se ha entendido, preguntarmelo.

Muchas gracias por ayudar!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes optar en el componente B por hacer 'Observable' tu variable para así poder suscribirte a los cambios que se produzcan en ella tanto desde el componente A como el B.

```
export class BComponent {

  inputVariableBChange = new BehaviorSubject<number[]>([]);
  get inputVariableB(): number[] { return this.inputVariableBChange.value; }
  @Input() set inputVariableB(values: number[]) { return this.inputVariableBChange.next(values); }

  constructor() {
    this.inputVariableBChange.subscribe((values: number[]) => {
      // Aquí tienes los nuevos valores de tu inputVariableB.
    })
  }

  tuFuncion(): void {
    // Aquí modificas (notificas/emites) cambios en tu inputVariableB.
    const values = []; // Nuevos valores...
    this.inputVariableBChange.next(values);
  }

}
```

Comment: Buenas, no entiendo que es un BehaviorSubject, y porque me dices de crear un  Observable si no defines la variable como tal?

Comment: Hola @PictorGames, un BehaviorSubject es una clase que hereda de Observable (http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/BehaviorSubject.js~BehaviorSubject.html). Por lo tanto puede hacer lo mismo que un Observable pero con añadidos, por ejemplo la manera de obtener el valor actual directamente con la variable 'value' o de emitir un nuevo valor con el método 'next'.

Comment: no tengo forma... en la Variable del componente A sigue sin setearse con el nuevo contenido del componente B

Comment: en el componente A estás suscrito al cambio de la variable del componente B y de ahí actualizas la variable del componente A?

Comment: En el componente A añado el contenido de la variable, y en el componente B lo modifico. Lo que pasa esque luego necesito el valores modificados en el componente A

Comment: O desde el A emites también sobre esa variable, o mejor aún un servicio entre ambos componentes sería lo suyo con el mismo sistema descrito en la respuesta.